# Rails 4.2: child of has_many cannot access parent record if parent is a new record when using accepts_nested_attributes_for

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I have an association that looks like:

```
class Parent < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :children
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :children
end

class Child < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :parent
end
```

In Rails 4.1.6, I can do:

```
parent = Parent.new # => #<Parent id: nil>
child = parent.children.new # => #<Child id: nil, parent_id: nil>
child.parent # => #<Parent id: nil>
```

However, in Rails 4.2.5, `child` cannot access `parent` if `parent` is not persisted:

```
parent = Parent.new # => #<Parent id: nil>
child = parent.children.build # => #<Child id: nil, parent_id: nil>
child.parent # => nil
```

One solution I've found is to not use the `children` accessor to build the record, e.g.:

```
parent = Parent.new # => #<Parent id: nil>
child = Child.new(parent: parent) # => #<Child id: nil, parent_id: nil>
child.parent # => #<Parent id: nil>
```

But this is a little less than satisfactory and I'll need to make changes in several places.

Is this by design? I can't find anything in Rails issues or in the changelogs (but I haven't looked particularly hard).

In the mean time, is there a way to get this functionality back?

**EDIT:**

I've done some good old fashioned binary dissection and discovered that the problem lies with `accepts_nested_attributes_for :children` on `Parent`. I have updated the title and the model to match.

**EDIT:**

This is a [known bug](https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/20451) so I will just have to work around it for now. I'll post back if I find a solution.

Answer (score 2):

Rails 4.2 introduced the [Adequate Record replacement](http://tenderlovemaking.com/2014/02/19/adequaterecord-pro-like-activerecord.html) to the existing ActiveRecord framework. It's possible that this behaviour was lost in the conversion.

The `build` method is the recommended way to do this if you're constructing within a scope:

```
parent.children.build
```

The `new` method may not produce identical results.

It's also worth noting that the [`acts_as_tree`](https://github.com/rails/acts_as_tree) and [ancestry](https://github.com/stefankroes/ancestry) Rails extensions might fix this, so those are both worth exploring.

Answer (score 0):

**Self-answer:**

As per [this issue](https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/20451), I set `inverse_of` on the `has_many` association and this has fixed my issue.

My `Parent` model now looks like:

```
class Parent < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :children, inverse_of: :parent
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :children
end
```